# Load Mixed-Mode dll from class library

Tags: c#, mixed-mode

So i have a mixed-mode dll what i would like to load from my C# class library. But im getting this error:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

So i did some searching and figured out that i should add this to my app.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

But now there is the problem, since im trying to load that mixed mode dll from class library i dont have the app.config file.

How could i resolve this problem?

Comment: Ideally you would recompile the mixed-mode DLL with the 4.0 runtime. Failing that, you add the app.config to the EXE project that's using your class library.

Comment: You always have either a web.config or an app.config. It is the responsibility of the application to configure this.

Comment: I tried adding App.config to the dll but that didnt help.

Comment: Yes, you should add the App.config to the end application. It the dll is reused by others, you should tell them how to configure their application to work with that dll.

Comment: I have added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" to the application but im still getting this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this blog post when googling:

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

It's exactly what i wanted and it works!